# How to get number of files open in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, utility, files

I would like to know if there is some utility that can show how many open files I have on an Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As root

```
lsof | wc -l
```

This will give you the number of lines returned by lsof. This utility lists all open files, including things like network sockets, so also **man lsof** for more options on what types of files are displayed.

Comment: You need to correct typo in answer. Should be `lsof | wc -l`. You don't have a space before the -l

Comment: I get `lsof: no pwd entry for UID 999` entries above the total. How can I get rid of those too?